# How to enable AspNetBufferingWrapper in .Framework ASP.NET WebApi 2 project using NLog?

Tags: nlog

How to use NLog's AspNetBufferingWrapper in .Framework (not core!) ASP.NET WebApi 2 project (possibly with OWIN)?

Hello! I got lost in NLog documentation. At first, we have [NLog.Web](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web) and it's said we need to add it to extensions like this:

```
  <!-- enable ASP.NET layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
  </extensions>
```

and add http module to `<system.webServer>`

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
        <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Web" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

this, should enable support of [AspNetBufferingWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetBufferingWrapper-target)  as I understand, and it should add support of asp-net specific layout renders. ASP.NET Setup instructions said that we need adding http module to `<system.web>` (not `<system.webServer>`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
   <httpModules>
    <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Web"/>
   </httpModules>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I guess it doesn't really matter except we need also add `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false">` to make it work.

Now I finally add this target to my NLog.config:

```
 <!--<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">-->
 <target name="elastic" xsi:type="AspNetBufferingWrapper">
     <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
            includeAllProperties="true"
             index="${environment}-${lowercase:${projectName}}-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
             uri="http://localhost:9200"
             layout="${message}">
         <field name="hostName" layout="${hostname}" />
         <field name="environment" layout="${environment}" />
     </target>
 </target>
```

and nothing happened ((( Commented configuration with `BufferingWrapper` works as expected but without asp-net specific properties passed to Elastic.

Afterwards, I decided to check official [example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/examples/ASP.NET%204.6.1/Visual%20Studio%202017/ASP.NET%204.6.1%20-%20VS2017) but as it turns out, it doesn't have neither http module setup nor BufferingWrapper.

I also found and tried to use `NLog.Owin.Logging package` but it have no dependencies with `NLog.Web` and I guess it is used for another purpose?

At the end I found that, for instance, `${aspnet-request-url}` render is available and was written to the File target...

So the questions, I guess, are: "How to make AspNetBufferingWrapper work and should I?", "What configuration options/packages should I really use?" and "Why aspnet-* properties there not added to log event properties when I was using BufferingWrapper?"

Comment: What version of `NLog.Web`-nuget-package are you using ?

Comment: 5.2.3 - latest at the moment of writing

Comment: Have you tried to enable the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) at Debug-level and looked for clues? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Comment: Yep, sure. It says it's ok

Comment: Have updated the [example project](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/examples/ASP.NET%204.6.1/Visual%20Studio%202017/ASP.NET%204.6.1%20-%20VS2017) to include registration of `NLogHttpModule` in the `web.config` (using both modes).

Answer (score 0):

There 2 modes to register HttpModule in ASP.NET MVC using web.config

**<system.webServer>** modules for integrated mode:

```xml
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Web" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

**<system.web>** httpModules for classic mode:

```xml
  <system.web>
     <httpModules>
      <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

You can have both modes enabled at the same time in `web.config`. See also: https://serverfault.com/q/282093